# How to disable completion-at-point in emacs shell (i.e., so I can have my `TAB` key back)?

Tags: key-bindings, completion, shell

Any suggestions on how to disable completion-at-point in Emacs shell (see below)?

I've looked in the [GNU docs on the relevant hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion-in-Buffers.html) (which is oddly named) - completion-at-point-functions - but given that the hook's value is simply a list of available functions, it's not clear to me how I can use it as a toggle.

The goal is to be able to have my `TAB` key back when using the Emacs shell.  I'd also be okay with turning off `completion-at-point-functions` globally (since I'm an `ido` junkie) but I'm not sure how to do that for global minor modes.

As reference, this is the window I'm referring to:

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE   DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS    DEFAULTS_PATH
```

Comment: Firstly, eshell uses `pcomplete` by default, `completion-at-point` is a fallback (call `M-x find-function RET eshell-pcomplete` to see it). Second, what do you mean when you say you want your “tab key back”? Do you want it to insert a tab character “\t”?

Comment: Am not claiming that `completion-at-point` is the default in eshell...  Yes, that's correct, I'd like to be able to insert a tab character "\t" using the <TAB> key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook (lambda () (define-key comint-mode-map "\t" 'self-insert-command)))
```

Comment: I get the following error after adding it to my `init.el` file: `Symbol's value as variable is void: comint-mode-map`.  Should work conceptually though.

Comment: You need to do that after entering comint-mode. I've updated the example to show you what I mean. This is general: when you want to do something for a particular mode, you typically want to do in on the hook for that mode. See [this question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/990/105).

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thanks for bearing with me, am new to emacs lisp

Comment: No problem. We are all learning, all the time. That's what this site is for.