# Where should I include a lazy initialization?

Tags: init-file, hooks

I want to add a specific key binding  to latex-mode:

`(define-key latex-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") 'my-latex-defun)`

At the same time I want to set it only when the specific mode is loaded. So I would like to know if there is a preference (best practice) between using the appropriate hook (`latex-mode-hook`) to accomplish that or using the clause `(with-eval-after-load "tex-mode" ...` to wrap the key binding definition. I tested both and they work fine, however I wonder which one is the right way to do it.

Comment: `with-eval-after-load` is loaded *once*, so a keymap-change goes there.  Hooks load *every time the mode is run*, e.g. on loading a new file associated with the mode, or however the hook is defined.  You would load e.g. `flyspell-mode` or `hl-line-mode` in a hook.  In my `init.el` I use `with-eval-after-load` approximately 160 times and `add-hook` 110 times.  A lazy init is a good init (IMO).

Comment: @rasmus sounds like an answer if you have the time :)  The distinction of how many times the code is run is the main one to consider, in my opinion.  (It's also the only one I can think of…)

Comment: For why it is a bad idea to change key bindings in mode hooks see http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/990/differences-between-setting-major-mode-keys-with-a-hook-versus-adding-them-to-th/996#996

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## A lazy init is a good init.

<sup>(IMO)</sup>

#### When to use `with-eval-after-load`

`with-eval-after-load` is loaded *once* when a certain *feature* or *file* is *first* loaded, so a keymap-change clearly goes inside one of these.  Not the least because the keymap may not be known at init-time [try something like `(define-key message-mode-map (kbd "C-c f") 'Footnote-add-footnote)` in `emacs -q`].  A hook is not a *nice* solution here since it binds the function to a key *every* time the hook is started.  As [tarsius](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/306/tarsius) notes, you can [read more](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/990/differences-between-setting-major-mode-keys-with-a-hook-versus-adding-them-to-th/996#996) about why *not* to `local-set-key` in hooks.

Finally, note that `with-eval-after-load` of GNU Emacs 24.4 is a 2 line wrapper around `eval-after-load` where `body` need not be quoted.

#### When to use hooks

Hooks are list of functions loaded every time a criterion is met, e.g. a certain mode is started.  A common use of hooks is to load minor-modes, such as `flyspell-mode` or `hl-line-mode`.  E.g. `(add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode)`.  As [Rémi](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2237/r%c3%a9mi) points out, `add-hooks` is smart and will do the right thing even if the hook-variable has yet to been loaded.  Nonetheless, I have many clauses like the following, which may be negligible for speed-gains, but does gives a sense of organization and dependency-structure:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org-agenda
  (add-hook 'org-agenda-mode-hook 'hl-line-mode))
```

Why add to hook after `org-agenda`?  As always, `C-h v org-agenda-mode-hook C-j` delivers.  The hook is defined in `org-agenda.el` as shown in `*help*`.

#### Loading extra features `with-eval-after-load`

`with-eval-after-load` is also important for loading extra features.  You'd probably want something like `(with-eval-after-load 'org  (require 'org-inlinetask))` to load org inlinetasks.  To see why `(find-library "org-inlinetask")`.  Since `org-inlinetasks.el` directly `(require 'org)`, all of the nice `autoload` that your friendly Emacs maintainers took great care to provide will be "ignored" and all of `org.el(c)` will be loaded.

But what if your (personal) `defun` is required several places?  If you are really picky, you could put the `defun`s in another file in your `load-path` and add `autoload` cookies, or you can tell Emacs where to find the function with the `autoload` function.  Then something like this would work:

```
(autoload 'org-cdlatex-mode "org" "cdlatex mode from org.")
(with-eval-after-load "latex"
  (add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook 'org-cdlatex-mode))
```

Or you could just `require` `org` as it in turn would pull `cdlatex`

And, honestly, personal defun ain't gonna matter much for init time most of the time.  The 1150 lines of personal defuns (84 defuns) in my `init.el` adds 0.02s over vanilla Emacs.

#### Measuring initialization time

An easy way to approximate intitialization time is

```
time emacs --eval "(kill-emacs)"
```

(benchmark against `emacs -q`.

But to get a more detailed approximation of where the initialization bottlenecks are check out Joe Schafer's [`esup`](https://github.com/jschaf/esup/).

Finally, loading time does not disappear magically.  You are only pushing it forward (to the extend that you use all features in each session).

Comment: You don't need to put add-hook in a with-eval-after-load, because add-hook will bind the variable if it's not already there.

Comment: You are right!  Could there still be speed gains from it though?  [I will try to update the answer later to reflect this]

Comment: What about defuns that later I would like to bind to a hook or key binding. Should I define a defun outside the `with-eval-after-load` without loosing lazy initialization advantages?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to your suggestions of `eval-after-load` and using a hook, let me suggest `use-package.el`.  You can do what you need to with

```
(use-package latex
  :ensure auctex
  :bind ("<f6>" . my-latex-defun))
```

LaTeX won't be loaded until *after* you request it.

Just as a side note: careful use of `use-package` has cut my startup times down to under a second.  (It used to take around four seconds.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've also contemplated to use use-package but I really want to figure it out how to do it without additional packages.

Comment: @jrbalderrama note that `use-package` is set to ship with Emacs 25.