# Symbol's value as variable is void: xah-fly-leader-keymap

Tags: init-file

I have been enjoying `Xah Fly Keys` by @XahLee and I am trying to create my own keymap for some `org-mode` functions.  I have read the [helpful documentation](http://ergoemacs.org/misc/xah-fly-keys_customization.html).  I used this section as a template for my keymap:
Add or Change Leader Key Sequence - Here's a example of creating a whole keymap

When I start `emacs` I get this error massage.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/root/.emacs':
Symbol's value as variable is void: xah-fly-leader-keymap
```

This is the part of my `.emacs` where I am trying to create the keymap.

```
(setq my-org-mode-keymap (make-sparse-keymap))
(define-key my-org-mode-keymap (kbd "o") 'org-meta-return)
(define-key my-org-mode-keymap (kbd "c") 'org-metaup)
(define-key my-org-mode-keymap (kbd "t") 'org-metadown)
(define-key my-org-mode-keymap (kbd "h") 'org-demote-subtree)
(define-key my-org-mode-keymap (kbd "n") 'org-promote-subtree)
(define-key my-org-mode-keymap (kbd "g") 'org-shiftright)

(define-key xah-fly-leader-key-map (kbd "o") my-org-mode-keymap)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symbol's value as variable is void: shell-mode-map](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35318/symbols-value-as-variable-is-void-shell-mode-map)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't load the library that defines `xah-fly-leader-key-map` before invoking that code. Try `require`ing that library.

Comment: @Drew thank you for linking to the other answer.  It helped me fix the error.  The error was because I had accidentally removed the `-` from `xah-fly-leader-key-map` so it was `xah-fly-leader-keymap` in a customization that had previously been working on.  As per your previous comment should I make this comment an answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, answering your own questions is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Drew thank you for linking to the other answer.
@wasamasa thanks for your help on IRC Freenode emacs-beginners.

The error was because I had accidentally removed the `-` from `xah-fly-leader-key-map` so it was `xah-fly-leader-keymap` in a customization that had previously been working on and had been working fine.

The error was:

```
(define-key xah-fly-leader-keymap (kbd "-") 'exchange-point-and-mark)
```

The fix was:

```
(define-key xah-fly-leader-key-map (kbd "-") 'exchange-point-and-mark)
```